# Understanding colon null check in a query

Tags: sql

I came across the following query today, I could understand the purpose of the second condition in while,

```
select name  from table1 where name = :n1 or :n1 is null;
```

I can understand that n1 is substituted, but the seconds condition seems redundant. Even if there is a record with (name = null), the record will be fetched(OR condition) regardless of the the second condition. So what is the purpose of having a second condition?.

Comment: If n1 is null, return all rows (i.e. skip the name condition.)

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If n1 is null, return all rows (i.e. skip the name condition.)

[Posted as answer, as requested.]

Answer (score 2):

> :n1 is null;

It is called making the filter optional. It is used to bring all the records from `table1` when the input is `NULL`